# NPM Update messed up my package.json

Tags: node.js, npm

I had a package.json file that I have been using in my starter web projects base for months. Today I updated NPM to most current and get these errors when it just worked 2 days ago:

```
Darwin 15.4.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.6
npm ERR! path /Users/PackyTagliaferro/.npm/_locks/staging-5068d5ea0bd1bbae.lock
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13

npm ERR! Error: EACCES, open '/Users/PackyTagliaferro/.npm/_locks/staging-5068d5ea0bd1bbae.lock'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, open '/Users/PackyTagliaferro/.npm/_locks/staging-5068d5ea0bd1bbae.lock']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/Users/PackyTagliaferro/.npm/_locks/staging-5068d5ea0bd1bbae.lock' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/PackyTagliaferro/Sites/Starter-WP/npm-debug.log
```

Very scared it messed up all my projects and even more scared now if I ever updated Node.js or NPM my projects will break.

Comment: Most likely you or npm somehow messed up the access rights or ownership in your `.npm` directory. You could try `sudo chown -R $(whoami) "$HOME/.npm"` to set all _user_ and _group_  setting in the `.npm` to your user. ( [Errno: -13 Failed to npm install #8958](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/8958) )

Comment: That worked to get it going but now it looks like it loaded a billion npm files in my modules folder, most of which were not defined as devDependencies

Comment: The newer versions of npm install all sub-dependencies in the base of the node_modules folder. That's why you're seeing more modules than you're used to.

Comment: AHhhhhh, I was really curious to where those came from